# Delete Cells Based on Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a help with a cell-deletion script. In general, I want to run a reset script that clears out all of the data up to the day I run it. Because I am statically inputting values into those cells that are matching up with information from a filter, I believe I need to delete those cells to properly line up my inputs with where the filter information will be after I delete the expired rows from the exporting page.

Here's what I want to do in my script: If the Column F value < today's date, then delete the cells in I, J, and K and shift the cells below them up. I think I found code to do this, but it takes so long to run that the program times out before it can get through more than a few rows. I will use a for loop to run it over 73 pages, so if it is lagging out on one...yeah, I need help!

```
function deleteEntries() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var datarange = ss.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var values = datarange.getValues();

  var currentDate = new Date();

  for (i = lastrow; i >= 5; i--) {
    var tempdate = values[i-1][5];

    if (tempdate < currentDate)  
    {
      ss.getRange(i-1, 8).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
      ss.getRange(i-1, 9).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
      ss.getRange(i-1, 10).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}}}
```

Comment: could yo share your spreadsheet please I'll help you with that live if you want. Best.

Comment: JSmith, can you shoot me your email address so I can share it with you?

Comment: just share the link I will send you a request for granting access to it. Thanks

Comment: Why not delete the three cells at the same time? `ss.getRange(i-1, 8, 1, 3)...` Better yet, if column F is chronologically sorted, you just need to iterate the in-memory array `values` until you find the first date that is not `<` today, and delete the previous rows.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aoKRvBKgnFl-5Ci-0BLEORp64OcRgKLpjitLZInreh0/edit#gid=1359303212

Comment: I've just sended you the request

Comment: the spreadsheet is too heavy and chat isn't activated as their are too muche restrictions. do you have formulas in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Unprotecting now. I have a lot of formulas, but they all stem down to filters, queries, and sort(filters).

Comment: you need to unprotect everything I guss so chat is activated. btw tehhowch solution seems th best for the moment

Answer (score 2):

In accordance with Apps Script ["best practices"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services), you will want to limit the use of the Spreadsheet Service to improve execution times. There are two "immediate" optimizations that can be considered:

1. Delete more than 1 cell at a time in a row
   To do this, simply select a 1-row x 3-column range: `ss.getRange(i-1, 8, 1, 3)` instead of selecting `(i-1, 8)`, `(i-1, 9)`, `(i-1, 10)` and calling `deleteCells` on each of the three `Ranges`.
2. Sort your sheet before deleting such that only 1 delete call is necessary (e.g. the [C++ stdlib "erase-remove" idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)). If your data is sorted based on column F, such that all data that should be removed is at the end, then you simply need to iterate the in-memory array (a *very* fast process) to locate the first date that should be removed, and then remove all the data below & including it.

An implementation of option 2 would look like this (**I assume you use frozen headers, as they do not move when the sheet or range is sorted**).

```
function sortDescAndGetValuesBack_(s, col) {
  return s.getDataRange().sort({column: col, ascending: false}).getValues();
}
function deleteAllOldData() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
      .filter(function (sheet) { /** some logic to remove sheets that this shouldn't happen on */});
  const now = new Date();
  const dim = SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS;

  sheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
    var values = sortDescAndGetValuesBack_(sheet, 6); // Col 6 = Column F
    for (var i = sheet.getFrozenRows(), len = values.length; i < len; ++i) {
      var fVal = values[i][5]; // Array index 5 = Column 6
      if (fVal && fVal < now) { // if equality checked, .getTime() is needed
        console.log({message: "Found first Col F value less than current time",
                     index: i, num2del: len - i, firstDelRow: values[i],
                     currentTime: now, sheet: sheet.getName()});
        var delRange = sheet.getRange(1 + i, 8, sheet.getLastRow() - i, 3);
        console.log({message: "Deleting range '" + sheet.getName() + "!" + delRange.getA1Notation() + "'"});
        delRange.deleteCells(dim);
        break; // nothing left to do on this sheet.
      }
    }
    console.log("Processed sheet '" + sheet.getName() + "'");
  });
}
```

References:

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Range#sort`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))
- [`Range#deleteCells`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#deleteCells(Dimension))